# Automatically update Stack Exchange About pages as the site moves through the various stages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0

Related: [This question on meta.programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/the-parent-sites-about-link-still-says-its-in-private-beta)

The Programmers.SE moved into Public Beta a week ago, but its [about](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about) page still says it's in private beta.

It might be an idea to automatically update the page as the site moves through the various stages, so that Jeff or whoever doesn't need to manually go through and change things.  The text that's there at the moment looks fairly stock-standard, but if you want to change certain bits I suppose you could make it somehow boilerplate, so the "Status" is a module that's automatically populated.

Answer (score 1):

Er.. no it doesn't?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about

> This site is currently in public beta. Anyone may participate. The purpose of the public beta is to:
>
> - record metrics about questions, answers, and traffic
> - grow the Q&A community around the topic
> - determine if the site attracts a viable audience

That's always been the case, there is private and public beta text that auto-changes, for quite a while now.

Comment: You're right, it's updated now.  It must have been misbehaving somehow, though; I've never been to the page before yesterday, so it can't have been cached, but the screenshot was what I saw.  Bug?